# Setting umask for a user with no shell?

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, chmod, cifs, umask

How can I set the [umask](/questions/tagged/umask) for the Apache user to have files default to `-rwxrwx---`?

I have an application that wants one directory to have either `0750` or `0770` permissions, which is great if it’s local, but if I try mount the directory on a [cifs](/questions/tagged/cifs) share, `chmod` has no effect on the directory mount point permissions.

I’ve read that if the umask is set differently, it will mount properly - just am unsure how to do that.

Comment: You will need to set the umask for whatever software is running as the apache user (presumably Apache httpd, or something running thereunder?). Adding Windows sharing protocols compounds the troubles.

Comment: @thrig - the share I have available is presented as CIFS (by a *nix box somewhere) - NFS is not an option here